# git において、 stage されたファイルに対するパーミッション一覧を取得するには？

Tags: git

git において、 staging された、 index 上のファイルに対して、その index 上でのパーミッション一覧を表示したくなりました。実行権限を正しく設定した上で add できているかどうかの確認を行いたいのが目的です。

これを実現する方法はありますか。

特に、いろいろ chmod しながら作業を行っていて (worktree 上の権限はいくつか変更されていて)、そのうち部分的に add をした場合など、今まさに stage されたファイルたちだけについてのパーミッションを取得したくなっているのですが、これを自明に行える方法がわからないと感じているので、質問しています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

とりあえず `git diff --summary --cached` はいかがでしょうか。ただし、これは新規作成またはパーミッション変更があったファイルしか表示してくれませんが。

```
$ git init .
$ touch a b c
$ chmod +x a
$ git add -A
$ git diff --summary --cached
 create mode 100755 a
 create mode 100644 b
 create mode 100644 c
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
[master (root-commit) 151bf09] first commit
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 a
 create mode 100644 b
 create mode 100644 c
$ chmod +x b
$ echo c > c
$ git add -A
$ git diff --summary --cached
 mode change 100644 => 100755 b
```

ステージしたファイルすべてについて情報を表示したいのであれば、無理矢理ですが次のようにすればできます。

```
$ git diff --summary --cached 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 -- $(git diff --name-only --cached)
 create mode 100755 b
 create mode 100644 c
```

`4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` は空のブランチのハッシュです。これからの diff をステージされたファイルについてのみ表示しています。

ただしこれはリポジトリのルートで実行しなければいけません。またファイル名に空白が含まれる場合はこのままではうまくいきません。

Answer (score 0):

xargsが使えるなら、こんな感じでも取得できそうですかね。

`git diff --cached --name-only | xargs ls -l`